# How to change JDK location in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, kotlin

When I open my project in Android Studio I see default JDK
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP8HN.png]

I went to settings and tried to change jdk but it didn't save. The previos path is still showed in Android Studio
[image]

I saw other threads, one of my path doesn't contains s whitespace.

Should I change something in my gradle.kts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java -version
```

Would help us to know to the current java version. To switch between the installed java versions, `update-java-alternatives` would help.

To list all java versions installed in the device

```
update-java-alternatives --list
```

To set a java version as default,

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set <path_to_installed_java_version>
```

Comment: java version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194, mixed mode)

Others commands are "not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: @Wafi_ck : Which OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 10, 64bit

Comment: @Wafi_ck : The above commands only works for OS based on ubuntu. Please refer (https://superuser.com/questions/262757/changing-current-version-of-java-within-windows) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can change File > Project Structure > SDK Location

[image]

OR, You can change local.properties files

Sample:

```
sdk.dir=D\:\\Sdk
```

Comment: Other projects use the same path in local.properties 
e.g. sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\------\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
but they have different JDK

Comment: Could you try?
File > Project Structure > SDK Location

Comment: Try to change path for SDK?

Comment: Change JDK path

Answer (score 1):

The built-in JRE is located in the Android Studio installation directory:

```
.../AndroidStudio...<bla-bla>/jre/
```

You can temporarily remove this 'jre' directory
(or archive)

Launch Android Studio, open any project.

After that, an error message will appear that Android Studio default JDK was not found, and a dialog for selecting it will appear.

There you can select any of your JDKs, which will become the Android Studio default JDK.

All new projects will be created using it.

After that, do not forget to return the JRE directory in the Android Studio installation directory from the archive to its place.

**Another way (according to Android Feng Shui)**

There are also special environment variables for Android Studio:

`STUDIO_JDK` - Sets the location of the JDK with which to run Android Studio. When you launch the IDE, it checks the STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME, and JAVA_HOME environment variables in that order.

`STUDIO_GRADLE_JDK` - Sets the location of the JDK that Android Studio uses to start the Gradle daemon. When you launch the IDE, it first checks STUDIO_GRADLE_JDK. If STUDIO_GRADLE_JDK is not defined, the IDE uses the value set in the Project Structure dialog.

[Android user guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables)

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidStudio2020.3.1, I couldn't set the 'default JDK' Settings.I found the JDK XML Settings for AndroidStudio using the "grep" command.It's located in 'C:\Users\Palmer\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\options\jdk.table.xml'in Windows.
I delete it. And the SDK initialization screen appears.
[SDK initialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqKZT.png)The next step is to initialize the AndroidStudio.
Or simply change the default JDK,Modify the XML file to change the JDK version[jdk version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMQQ6.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Regardless of the format, it really helped - the new android studio does not allow simply change this and the XML file does contain the config path.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes as it's the only way to clean or "reset" the internal config of Android Studio.